# How can I tell if my serial card supports RS-485?

Tags: serial-port

It's a Rosewill RC-300 1 Port serial PCI adapter.  From http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815166003, it says "The Rosewill RC-300 features a 9-pin RS232 serial port to add..." so I assume it only supports RS-232?  Sorry for the ignorant question; I tried looking up differences between the specifications but it's pretty complicated for me.

Comment: You can obtain a [converter](http://www.dinowish.com/stores/buybay005/-p-5867.html). You'll get much more useful answers if you tell us what, specifically, you're trying to do. "Supports" is a very vague term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you've bought a card that specifically supports RS485, no, you don't have it.

RS232 uses at a minimumum, three wires. A transmit, a receive and signal ground. The signal is a swing of around +-15VDC on the receive and transmit wires and is referenced to the ground wire.

RS485 is a differential balanced signal (one wire swings positive while the other swings negative) over twisted pair, similar to what Ethernet uses and typically is used for CSU/DSU units, process control, etc. Full Duplex requires two twisted pairs.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the manual to suggest the RC-300 supports RS-485

Other vendor's [product descriptions](http://www.sealevel.com/store/serial/asynchronous-serial/pci.html) generally do say if they support RS-485.

RS-485 is a more specialised comms standard than RS-232, mainly used in industrial systems

Comment: and I don't think Rosewill makes industrial serial pci cards.